# Does gravity increase with mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass

Alright so I think it's a really stupid questions but I know for a fact that more the mass, more will be gravity. But one student of mine came up with the equation:

$$ w = mg$$

where $w$ is the weight, and according to that, mass and gravity are inversely proportional.

Anyone kind enough to explain?

Comment: You need to make precise what you mean by "gravity".  Is it the force of gravity?  Also, is your "$w=mg$" equation is suppose to mean $\text{weight}=\text{mass}\times\text{gravitational acceleration}$, where "weight" is defined as the gravitational force experienced by the object?  If that is the case and the gravitational acceleration, $g$, is constant--as it is near the surface of the Earth--then what makes you think that the mass and the force of gravity are inversely proportional?  They look proportional to my eyes

Comment: Mathematically, that would be true if mass could vary with weight remaining fixed. That's not how the universe is designed, however. Mass is an inherent property of an object (at least, at a macroscopic level; I'm not getting into Higgs fields here), while its weight is simply something we measure in a given gravitational field.

Comment: -1. Not clear what situation you are asking about. You need to add more detail to explain your difficulty.

Comment: The important thing to know: if you see some confusing things, **see always the equations first**. The mathematical formulas are always clear, what is unclear is the natural language talking about them.

Answer (score 5):

No, $w=mg$ means that in weaker gravity, you need to have more mass, to have the same weight.

But if you have the same mass in stronger gravity, then you will have more weight.

Comment: This is the only answer needed. Weight is not constant.  Nether is gravitational field strength (g). Only mass.

Answer (score 3):

The *gravitational force* with *magnitude* $F_{g}$, exerted on an object of *mass* $m$ by earth of mass $M$, is calculated by (Newton's Law of Gravity)
$$
F_{g}=G\frac{mM}{R^2},
$$
where $G$ is *gravitational constant*. If we assume that the object is on the surface of the earth then $R$ is the radius of the earth. The magnitude of the *weight* of the object, $W$, is nothing but the gravitational force exerted on the object, therefore we can write
$$
F_{g}=W=G\frac{mM}{R^2}.
$$
If we invoke Newton's second law (force equals to mass times acceleration), 
$$
F_{g}=ma=G\frac{mM}{R^2},
$$
then we reach to the conclusion that the magnitude of acceleration
$$
a=G\frac{M}{R^2}.
$$
The radius and the mass of earth, as well as $G$, being constant, this acceleration is a constant and referred to as *gravitational acceleration*, $g$.

With all given equations above one can conclude:

If the mass of the object increases (while the mass of the earth is constant) then the gravitational force, that is, the weight of the object increases.

If the mass of the earth of increases (while the mass of the object is constant) then $g$ increases and hence the gravitational force, that is, the weight of the object increases.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $w = mg$ comes from two different contributors. $m$ is just some mass of object and $g$ is the gravitational attraction from another object in this case it is usually the mass of the Earth.

If you expand the definition of weight as the gravitational force attraction between object and Earth, you will get:

$W = F_{g} = GMm/r^{2}$, where $G$ is gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the Earth and $r$ is the distance between the objects.

Then you cancel the $m$ and you get: $g = GM/r^{2}$, which when the mass $M$ increases then the gravitational attraction also increases. So this proves that when a mass increase the gravity is also greater.

Comment: While the other answers are correct, I think this one captures the OP's confusion — namely that $m$ and $g$ does not refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

That the formula $w=mg$ exists says nothing about what $g$ is or what it contains.

Furthermore, you are comparing to the wrong mass. The $m$ here is the mass that is being pulled in (accelerated by $g$). It is not the mass that pulls.

The formula for $g$ comes from Newton's law if gravity:

$$g=GM/r^2$$

and contains the mass $M$ of that which pulls. This mass is of course the earth's and the distance $r$ is the distance from the earth core.